# How to make java application packge installable on Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, fedora

I have a java application .exe file which runs on windows. But i want to run the same application on Linux. How can i change that .exe file in rpm,debian package or change that java application in rpm package. Please help me out.

Comment: Java applications aren't exe files. And exe files won't run on linux. You could probably package your application into a RPM or a deb or both, but what have you tried?

Comment: @SaurabhShubham, What is wrong with `.jar` file?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, I dont know how to package  java application into RPM or DEB.

Comment: Do you know how to package any application into a RPM or DEB file? Note that your application (if an exe) still won't work on Linux.

Comment: Most probably you are packaging your java `.jar / .war / .ear` file in an exe. You need to decouple that and use the java jar/war directly on linux server.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sorry but I don't have any Idea about RPM and DEB files. I searched up, but didn't get so much that I can understand.

Comment: There are *books* on both topics, how can we possibly provide a complete answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradle to build debian packages : https://github.com/gesellix/gradle-debian-plugin
If you are using maven, you can try this : https://askubuntu.com/a/465251/75273

Answer (score 0):

.Exe wont be running on your linux system at any cause. Plus You need to convert You Application into different formats like Debian,tar,etc. Hope You know how to convert them... :|